# To get a value of a TD using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I got a very simple Table with only two rows. 
I was thinking what is the best way to get the value from the TD with ID "row2".

```
<Table id="testing>
<tr>
<th>
</th>
<td id="row1">hello</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
</th>
<td id="row2">world</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      var r=$("#testing":row2).val();
      alert(r);
});
```

But I couldn't see any message pop up.
What shall I do in the JQuery code if I want to specify the Table ID along with the TD ID?

```
 var r=$("#testing":row2).text();
 var r=$("#testing").children("row2").text();
```

Comment: There's no point in seeking a selector that uses the Table ID along with the TD ID. Element ID's are supposed to be unique in a page. Simply using the single TD ID will get you directly to that item

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
  var r = $("#testing #row2").text();
  alert(r);
```

[In action here](http://jsfiddle.net/6qxQW/) for your viewing pleasure.

Comment: Thanks Pat. Could you show me the Jquery code if I want to specify which Table the TD belongs to instead of just the TD ID.

Comment: Absolument - I've edited the code above to add the table's ID to the selector.  However, strictly speaking, this shouldn't be required in your case because an ID should be unique in the document (i.e. you shouldn't have any `row2` IDs anywhere else).  If you need multiple row2's, you could use classes:  `<td class="row2">`, in which case your selector would become `$("#testing .row2")`.  You can read more about selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.  The short version is that if the selector works in CSS, it'll work in jQuery.

Comment: after doing R&D and going through all of the code samples using blah blah techniques to get td data finally i landed here and found this very simple easy solution. Thanks mate. @Pat

Answer (score 6):

Use `text()` instead of `val()`

```
var r = $("#row2").text();
```

**More Info:**

- [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td class="tdcls">1</td>
    <td class="tdcls">2</td>
    <td class="tdcls">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tdcls">4</td>
    <td class="tdcls">5</td>
    <td class="tdcls">6</td>
</tr>
```

jquery code to select particular td value

```
$(".tdcls").mouseenter(function(){
    var a = $(this).text();
});
```

Comment: surely you will get the answer

Answer (score 0):

the TD ID is going to be unique be it in any table. It is not right to have two tables with TD ID's same in both tables. Therefore if you feel then append the table id for the TD ID like so: (and then use the answers above)

```
 <table id="test1">
    <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
    <td id="test1_row1">hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
    <td id="test1_row2">world</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

does this help?