# Failed get td text by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="rep">
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="assets/x.gif" class="r1"></td>
                <td id="l4" title="r1">5/1000</td>
                <td><img src="assets/x.gif" class="r2"></td>
                <td id="l3" title="r2">15/1000</td>
                <td><img src="assets/x.gif" class="r3"></td>
                <td id="l2" title="r3">152/1000</td>
                <td><img src="assets/x.gif" class="r4"></td>
                <td id="l1" title="r4">100/1000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="6"></td><td><img src="assets/x.gif" class="r5""></td><td>1000/1000</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Hi...
I was trying get value/text from td with id 11-14.
but using $('#14') or getElementById is always failed.
Already try using get all table but location index sometime change.
i hope someone can help me. thank

Comment: You have "**L**NUMBER"  as the id not a number so `$("l4")`...

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, it's a typo.

Comment: LNUMBER ?
sorry i dont understand what you mean.

Comment: @RamaMagfirah Your id `l4` is the letter `l` followed by `4` not the number `1` followed by `4`

Comment: @RamaMagfirah The id in this code sample  `<td id="l4" title="r1">` is actually 'l4' not '14'. That is the letter l followed by an integer number.

Comment: flagged as typographical error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378272/to-get-a-value-of-a-td-using-jquery  i have try method from that post, but still can take text from that id

Comment: oh shit, i confuse for around 4 hour just because 1 and l... Alex and yogur thank for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a L before the 4 and not a "one"
So you have to do this :

```
$("#l4")
```

And not

```
$("#14")
```

Comment: thank you... it;s my fault, type error. guess later will more careful and use copy paste for ID or class

Comment: @RamaMagfirah no problem, it happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

You've the L+NUMBER as mentioned in the comment :

```
     l1!=11
_____^    //Character 'l'
______^   //Number '1'
```

So you've just to use the real id's in your code :

```
$("#l1").text();
```

Comment: you are welcome :)